# Can't specify header in SOAP call using Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

When calling to an API for retrieving labels for post parcels I get frustrated with how hard it is to set up a SOAP call with ruby.

I know that the following works from a sandbox environment:

**this is the SHOULD BE call**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://postnl.nl/cif/services/BarcodeWebService/IBarcodeWebService/GenerateBarcode</Action>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>devc_!R4xc8p9</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GenerateBarcode xmlns:d6p1="http://postnl.nl/cif/domain/BarcodeWebService/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://postnl.nl/cif/services/BarcodeWebService/">
      <d6p1:Message>
        <d6p1:MessageID>5</d6p1:MessageID>
        <d6p1:MessageTimeStamp>28-06-2017 14:15:41</d6p1:MessageTimeStamp>
      </d6p1:Message>
      <d6p1:Customer>
        <d6p1:CustomerCode>DEVC</d6p1:CustomerCode>
        <d6p1:CustomerNumber>11223344</d6p1:CustomerNumber>
      </d6p1:Customer>
      <d6p1:Barcode>
        <d6p1:Type>3S</d6p1:Type>
        <d6p1:Range>DEVC</d6p1:Range>
        <d6p1:Serie>1000000-2000000</d6p1:Serie>
      </d6p1:Barcode>
    </GenerateBarcode>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**EDIT**

As sugested I used `build_request` to inspect how my request looks. It actually looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <Username>devc_!R4xc8p9</Username
    <Password>098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561</Password>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body><wsdl:GenerateBarcode><CustomerCode>DEVC</CustomerCode>
    <CustomerNumber>11223344</CustomerNumber>
    <Type>3S</Type>
    <Range>DEVC</Range>
    <Serie>1000000-2000000</Serie>
</wsdl:GenerateBarcode>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comparing that with the xml above, it becomes clear that stuff is off. How to handle nesting?

This is when I build it myself like:

```ruby
@client = Savon.client(
                :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase,
                :raise_errors => false,
                :pretty_print_xml => true,
                :wsdl => 'https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/?wsdl',
                :headers => {
                  'Username' => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
                  'Password' => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
                })

      @response = @client.call(:generate_barcode) do
        soap_header "Username" => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
                    "Password" => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
        message customer_code:   'DEVC',
                customer_number: 11223344,
                type:            '3S',
                range:           'DEVC',
                serie:           '1000000-2000000'
      end
```

I know my connection works, but also get back:

```
{:fault=>{:faultcode=>"s:CIF Framework Message Interceptor",
   :faultstring=>"Check CIFException in the detail section", :detail=>
     {:cif_exception=>{:errors=>{:exception_data=>{:description=>nil,
    :error_msg=>"Username/password is not specified.",
    :error_number=>"3"}},
  :@xmlns=>"http://postnl.nl/cif/services/common/", 
  :"@xmlns:i"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}}}}
```

So already in my header stuff goes wrong. Username/password is not specified. I've tried several combinations and I don't get why.

**Update**

```ruby
@client = Savon.client(
        :env_namespace => :s,
        # :namespace_identifier => :none, # :none doesn't work... gets interpreted literary. Out-commeting gives wsdl:GenerateBarcode 
        :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase,
        :raise_errors => false,
        :pretty_print_xml => true,
        :endpoint => 'https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/BarcodeWebService.svc',
        :wsdl => 'https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/?wsdl')

      soap_header = {
                      "Security" => {
                        "UsernameToken" => {
                          "Username" => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
                          "Password" => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
                        }
                      }
                    }


      message = {
                    "d6p1:Customer" => {
                      "d6p1:CustomerCode"    => 'DEVC',
                      "d6p1:CustomerNumber"  => 11223344
                    },
                    "d6p1:Barcode" => {
                      "d6p1:Type" => '3S',
                      "d6p1:Range" => 'DEVC',
                      "d6p1:Serie" => '1000000-2000000'
                    }
                }



      @request = @client.build_request(:generate_barcode) do
        soap_header soap_header
        message message
      end

      @response = @client.call(:generate_barcode) do
        soap_header soap_header
        message message
```

Which builds the following request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Security>
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>devc_!R4xc8p9</Username
        <Password>098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <wsdl:GenerateBarcode>
      <d6p1:Customer>
        <d6p1:CustomerCode>DEVC</d6p1:CustomerCode
        <d6p1:CustomerNumber>11223344</d6p1:CustomerNumber>
      </d6p1:Customer>
      <d6p1:Barcode>
        <d6p1:Type>3S</d6p1:Type>
        <d6p1:Range>DEVC</d6p1:Range>
        <d6p1:Serie>1000000-2000000</d6p1:Serie>
      </d6p1:Barcode></s:GenerateBarcode>
</s:Body>
```

For as of yet, I get errors adding the `wsse:` namespace straight in the `soap_header` hash.

**EDIT 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/"
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://postnl.nl/cif/services/BarcodeWebService/IBarcodeWebService/GenerateBarcode
    </Action>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <UsernameToken>
        <Username>devc_!R4xc8p9</Username>
        <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
      </UsernameToken>
    </Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <wsdl:GenerateBarcode>
      <d6p1:Customer>
        <d6p1:CustomerCode>DEVC</d6p1:CustomerCode>
        <d6p1:CustomerNumber>11223344</d6p1:CustomerNumber>
      </d6p1:Customer>
      <d6p1:Barcode>
        <d6p1:Type>3S</d6p1:Type>
        <d6p1:Range>DEVC</d6p1:Range>
        <d6p1:Serie>1000000-2000000</d6p1:Serie>
      </d6p1:Barcode>
    </wsdl:GenerateBarcode>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comparing this to my **should be** call it seems that my `<s:envelope ...>` tag has too much information.

I'll make a follow up question of this probably.

**EDIT 3**

I restarted at [Complex SOAP call in Ruby on Rails using Savon gets weird around the envelope and main operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967364/complex-soap-call-in-ruby-on-rails-using-savon-gets-weird-around-the-envelope-an)

Comment: try calling `build_request` instead of `call` in with this code in a console, it should output the request instead of attempting to make the request, and that can help see what is actually happening.

Comment: Thanks, added it in, right under the should-be xml. I seem to have difficulty with having my attributes nested. Can't I just have this xml call saved somewhere and use `#{}` interpolation to add variables? Would be so much easier than figuring this out again.

Comment: shouldn't your user/password be in the WSSE namespace?

Comment: Yes, need to look into name spacing. That combined with Michael Gormans answer should cut it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Message hash, should be nested in the same way as the call expects it something like

```
@client = Savon.client(
  :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase,
  :raise_errors => false,
  :pretty_print_xml => true,
  :wsdl => 'https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/?wsdl',
  :headers => {
    'Username' => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
    'Password' => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
})

@response = @client.call(:generate_barcode) do
  soap_header "Security" => {
                "UsernameToken" => {
                  "Username" => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
                  "Password" => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
                }
              }
  message "GenerateBarcode" => {
            "Message" => {
              "MessageID"   => 5, #might be different
              "MessageTime" => Time.now, #might be different depending on use case
            },
            "Customer" => {
              "CustomerCode"   => 'DEVC',
              "CustomerNumber" => 11223344
            },
            "Barcode" => {
              "Type"  => '3S',
              "Range" => 'DEVC',
              "Serie" => '1000000-2000000'
            }
          }
  end
```

**EDIT**

Referencing [this page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/savonrb/34YiN9wLgqI) it looks like you can add the action tag and elements like this

```
 'Action' =>  "http://postnl.nl/cif/services/BarcodeWebService/IBarcodeWebService/GenerateBarcode",
 :attributes! => {
   "s:mustUnderstand" => "1",
   "xmlns" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"
 }
```

Referencing [this page](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/305) it looks like you can set the namespaces directly "wsse:UsernameToken" instead of "UsernameToken"

which should result in the following

```
@client = Savon.client(
  :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase,
  :raise_errors => false,
  :pretty_print_xml => true,
  :wsdl => 'https://testservice.postnl.com/CIF_SB/BarcodeWebService/1_1/?wsdl',
  :headers => {
    'Username' => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
    'Password' => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
})

@response = @client.call(:generate_barcode) do
  soap_header "Security" => {
                "wsse:UsernameToken" => {
                  "wsse:Username" => 'devc_!R4xc8p9',
                  "wsse:Password" => '098fd559930983af31ef6630a0bb0c1974156561'
                }     
              "Action" =>  "http://postnl.nl/cif/services/BarcodeWebService/IBarcodeWebService/GenerateBarcode",
              :attributes! => {
                "s:mustUnderstand" => "1",
                "xmlns" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"
              }
            }
  message "GenerateBarcode" => {
            "Message" => {
              "MessageID"   => 5, #might be different
              "MessageTime" => Time.now, #might be different depending on use case
            },
            "Customer" => {
              "CustomerCode"   => 'DEVC',
              "CustomerNumber" => 11223344
            },
            "Barcode" => {
              "Type"  => '3S',
              "Range" => 'DEVC',
              "Serie" => '1000000-2000000'
            }
          }
  end
```

Comment: Almost there only the name spacing I need to fix. It's more like it though.

Comment: Three things you maybe know how to fix: How do I prefix the Envelope, Header and Body with `s:`. How to add this Action tag with its attributes and the other attributes. Finally why does prefixing with `wsse:` give me an error. I'll add my ruby.

Comment: I added how you could namespace the wsse components and add the action tag, but I am not sure on how to namespace the `envelope`, `header`, and `body` without name spacing the rest

Comment: I marked this as the answer, but the reality of my soap call is that it still doesn't work. This lead me in the right direction though. I'll make a follow up question soon. Thanks!

Comment: Here is my follow up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967364/complex-soap-call-in-ruby-on-rails-using-savon-gets-weird-around-the-envelope-an